# Retrieve remaining time between two dates considering business hours

Tags: php, datetime

**I am trying to write a php solution to calculate the planned end time considering the target in business hours.**

It shouldn't consider some days (retrieved from setting saved in db) such as holidays.
Also business hours are retrieved from db (morning_from (8:30am), morning_to (1:00pm), evening_from (2:30pm), evening_to (6:30pm)).

I want to develop this script because I want that my page shows the remaining time for technical resolution of an opened ticket every day.

**For example:**

> customer having contract with 10 working hours SLA opens a ticket
>   today (friday) 31/01/2020 16:00:00, considering that in the
>   *noBusinessDays = array("saturday", "sunday")* and *businessHours* set as mentioned before(8:30-13:00/14:30-18:30), the result will have to
>   be monday 3/02/2020 17:30:00.

**Code example:**

```
$noBusinessDays = array("saturday", "sunday");
$businessHours = array("morning_from" => "8:30", "morning_to" => "13:00", "evening_from" => "14:30", "evening_to" => "18:30");

$SLA = "10"; //hours

$ticketDate = new DateTime();
$ticketDate->setTimestamp(strtotime("31/01/2020 16:00:00"));

// I don't know how to use my arrays to say in this calculation how to use them
$maximumLimit = $ticketDate->add(new DateInterval("PT" . $SLA ."H"));
```

**Thank you** in advance.

Comment: So what are you stuck with?

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Edited with code example

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following function

```
// intersection of 2 time intervals
// input - Unix timestamps (start,end)
// output - intersection in seconds
function time_union($b_1,$e_1,$b_2,$e_2)
{
  return max(0,$e_1-$b_1 - max(0,$e_1-$e_2) - max(0,$b_2-$b_1));
}
```

You will start with an empty time interval `[X, Y)` where `X` is the timestamp of the ticket creation and `Y` initially is equal to `X`.

Then you start adding days to `Y` - one by one. Each time you expand the time interval to contain another day - you use the above function to check how much of the SLA hours are covered (i.e. overlapping) with the working hours in the day you have just added. If the day is marked as a holiday - you simple skip it and continue with the next date.

If you find out that SLA hours are partially covered with either the morning or evening business hours - you should simply subtract the extra hours.

In the end `Y` will be equal to the timestamp that you want to show in your application.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd break down the problem into pieces.  After calculating the total number of days in the interval, first dispose of the trivial case that it's all happening in one week.

begin by calculating the number of "whole weeks."  Each "whole week" is five business days.  Subtract the corresponding interval of time and proceed.  Now, look at the day-of-the-week of the start-date:  each day adds a certain number of days.  Then the day-of-week of the end date, likewise.  You can then consider hour-of-the-day as needed.

Holidays are a simple table:  if the day falls within the range, subtract one day.

Now ... having said all of that, the *very first* thing that I would do is to search GitHub and SourceForge!  Because I am extremely sure that somebody out there has already done this.  **:-D**

```
 "Actum Ne Agas:  Do Not Do A Thing Already Done."
```

Comment: Found some libs on GitHub but no one that does the calculation I need, can you link me the one that suits my case?